# Is there a way to delete labels in the system in hbase?

Tags: hbase

In HBase, a user can add labels to the system using the following command in shell:

```
add_labels ['one', 'two', three']
```

or in JAVA_API

```
VisibilityClient.addLabels(...)
```

My question is whether there is a chance to delete all these labels created at the system level ?

Answer (score 0):

clearAuths may help to delete from system .
http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hbase-0.98.6-cdh5.2.1/book/hbase.visibility.labels.html
https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/security/visibility/VisibilityLabelService.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply but as the API suggest, this clears the auths for a given user, not at the system level. I want to delete labels from the system.